# IPv6 route configuration only works some of the time

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6

I have a network which is brought online and accessible over a tunnel, tun0.
This tun0 is started with a python script as follows:

```
tun_name = 'tun0'.encode()
ifs = ioctl(self.virtualIf, TUNSETIFF, struct.pack("16sH", tun_name, IFF_TUN))
self.ifname = tun_name.decode()
print('[NetworkSideThread] Created virtual interface '+self.ifname+'.')

# configure IPv6 addresses of virtual interface
subprocess.check_call(CMD_IFCONFIG + ' ' + self.ifname + ' up', shell=True)
subprocess.check_call(CMD_IFCONFIG + ' ' + self.ifname + ' inet6 add ' + self.prefix + '::1/64', shell=True)
subprocess.check_call(CMD_IFCONFIG + ' ' + self.ifname + ' inet6 add fe80::1/64', shell=True)
print('[NetworkSideThread] Configured IPv6 address')

# set static route
subprocess.check_call(CMD_ROUTE+' -A inet6 add ' + self.prefix + '::/64 dev ' + self.ifname, shell=True)
```

Devices within the network all have a bbbb:: address (e.g., bbbb::17:d00:30:6fb6 and bbbb::17:d00:30:76f6).
Purpose is that traffic send from 76f6 to 6fb6 arrives at the tunnel and is then correctly send to 6fb6.

The odd thing is: with the above configuration, this only works some of the time!

Doing "route -A inet6" reveals:

```
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
2a02:2c40:500:a006::/64        [::]                       Ue   256 0     0 ens33
bbbb::/64                      [::]                       U    1   3   290 tun0
bbbb::/64                      [::]                       U    256 0     0 tun0
fe80::/64                      [::]                       U    256 1    38 ens33
fe80::/64                      [::]                       U    256 0     0 tun0
[::]/0                         gateway                    UG   100 1     1 ens33
[::]/0                         [::]                       !n   -1  1 16599 lo
ip6-localhost/128              [::]                       Un   0   5882117 lo
2a02:2c40:500:a006::/128       [::]                       Un   0   4     3 lo
ubuntu/128                     [::]                       Un   0   1     0 lo
ubuntu/128                     [::]                       Un   0   3    82 lo
bbbb::/128                     [::]                       Un   0   3     5 lo
ubuntu/128                     [::]                       Un   0   4    57 lo
fe80::/128                     [::]                       Un   0   3     6 lo
fe80::/128                     [::]                       Un   0   1     0 lo
ubuntu/128                     [::]                       Un   0   1     0 lo
ubuntu/128                     [::]                       Un   0   1     0 lo
ubuntu/128                     [::]                       Un   0   3    33 lo
ip6-mcastprefix/8              [::]                       U    256 4   610 ens33
ip6-mcastprefix/8              [::]                       U    256 0     0 tun0
[::]/0                         [::]                       !n   -1  1 16600 lo
```

My guess would be that sometimes traffic sent from 76f6 to 6fb6 takes the "2a02:2c40:500:a006::/64        [::]                       Ue   256 0     0 ens33" route and sometimes it takes the "bbbb::/64                      [::]                       U    1   3   290 tun0" route.

In all cases where a device sends to a bbbb address, the packet should be injected through the tunnel into the bbbb network.

Any clue on how to solve this? It is odd since it doesn't happen consistently.

Edit:

The requested info:

> ip -6 route get bbbb::17:d00:30:6fb6

gives

> bbbb::17:d00:30:6fb6 from :: dev tun0  src bbbb::1  metric 1  pref
>   medium

and

> ip route show match bbbb::17:d00:30:6fb6

gives nothing.

Hmmm, your first comment makes sense so my initial hypothesis is wrong.
For added info, I've added a screencapture of Wireshark on the tunnel, which shows identical packets in both the cases where it is received at 6fb6 and where it isn't (packets

This seems to indicate I was wrong. Not an immediate clue what the issue is then -- the receiving device might drop in some cases and not drop in others but that would be odd.

Wireshark gives the same results as well. The first 3 packets are the first transmission and arrive at the destination, the last 3 packets (though identical) are the second transmission and don't arrive!
[image]

Comment: Why do you think packets sent to `bbbb::17:d00:30:6fb6` can match the route `2a02:2c40:500:a006::/64` if it has a _completely different prefix_?

Comment: Also, could you inspect `ip -6 route get bbbb::17:d00:30:6fb6` and `ip route show match bbbb::17:d00:30:6fb6` the next time it breaks? (Is there even a particular reason to be using `ifconfig` and `route` on Linux, instead of the native `ip` tool? Not only is the `route` output harder to read, more importantly it _omits a lot of possible values._)

Comment: I've added the requested info.
Sorry, probably because googling for answers gave those commands!

Comment: I've also added a wireshark capture

Comment: I forgot the `-6` in the 2nd command, but it doesn't matter – `ip -6 route get` shows the correct route anyway. What software operates the tun0 interface? (I'm assuming you're writing some VPN software in Python?) Does the program see the packet, from tun0 on the sending side as well as via LAN on the receiving side?

Comment: An Embedded SmartMesh IP Manager operated with (a modified version of) SmartMesh SDK (https://dustcloud.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SMSDK).
This program sees packets from the transmitter.
The odd thing is that it sometimes drops and sometimes doesn't. I'm thinking of perhaps silent drops due to a buffer overflow, either at the receiver or at the tunnel.